# Explain this lambda

Tags: python, lambda, odoo

Below is a Python dictionary (from an OpenERP application), with fields being defaulted via lambda. I can see how to use this pattern, clearly 'active' is a boolean, 'level' an integer and 'price' a float.

But can someone explain exactly how this works? What is 'a' represent here?

```
_defaults = {
    'active': lambda *a: False,
    'level': lambda *a: 1,
    'price': lambda *a: 1.0,
    }
```

Comment: This is a weird programming pattern.

Comment: @JohnJohn2 Why do you think it's weird?

Comment: @JohnJohn2: Why? Returning constants for hooks that normally take a certain number of arguments, which are all ignored. This makes these callables widely applicable, regardless of the number of arguments each specific hook requires.

Comment: It's very common in OpenERP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*a` syntax captures any number of arguments; the lambdas accept 0 or more arguments and all return a constant value, regardless.

Essentially, these lambdas ignore any and all arguments passed in.

The syntax can be used in functions as well, and there is also a keyword argument equivalent in the form of `**keywords`, resulting in a mapping.

Quick demo:

```
>>> demo = lambda *a: a
>>> demo()
()
>>> demo(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

`demo` here returns whatever `*a` captured; a tuple of 0 or more values that were the arguments to the call.

Comment: So why would we need a lambda? Why not just put 'active' : 'False' ?

Comment: @ardochhigh: because you cannot *call* `False`; if these are passed to something that expects a function or other callable, you cannot just pass in a value.

Answer (score 1):

In old OpenERP version (up to 5.0 if I remember correctly) defaults could only be functions.

Those are fine where the default value actually needs to be computed somhow.

However, in some cases the default is just some constant, like `1.0`. A trivial function returning always `1.0` is then needed. The lambda expression allows to create such an function quickly:

```
_defaults = {
    'field': lambda *a: 1.0
}
```

is just a shorter way to write:

```
def f():
    return 1.0

_defaults = {
    'field': f
}
```

Recent versions of OpenERP / Odoo allow you to just specify a constant instead of a lambda funciont. So now you can also do:

```
_defaults = {
    'field': 1.0
}
```